# How to draw the graph of a function of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity, graphing-functions

[image]

$$y=\begin{cases} x^3 & x\le 1 \\ x & x \ge 1\end{cases}$$

Both are continuous at $x=1$. But not differentiate at the point.

Is the graph right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

To  the degree of detail.  For $x\le1$ the graph will resemble the graph of $y = x^3$, and for $x > 1$ the graph will resemble the graph $y = x$.  As at $x = 1$, both $x^3$ and $x$ equal $1$, the graph with "connect".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph generated with **MATHEMATICA**
[image]

---

Well, I have had installed the program in a PC. There are some sites where you can graph functions, but I'm not sure if you can get graphs with the same quality:

[Wolfram Alpha](http:////www.wolframalpha.com)

[Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/)

[Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/)

I hope they will be useful to you.

Comment: oh hi, may i know the site ??how can u draw like that~

Comment: Well, i have installed the program in a PC. There are some sites in the web where you can graph functions, but I'm not sure if you can get graphs with the same quality: Wolfram Alpha //www.wolframalpha.com

Answer (score 1):

The graph is correct, although the currently-attached statement $f'(x) = 3$ at $x \le 1$ is incorrect. It would be true to say that $f'(x) = 3x^2$ at $x < 1$, for which the limit of $f'(x)$ approaches 3 as $x$ approaches 1 from the left.

Comment: yes, i missed that part sorry,~